# Javascript / CMS / editEase - What JS/Frontend-embedded CMSs exist?

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, content-management

I stumbled across a CMS written in jQuery that enables the site to be managed from the frontend (backend functionality is embedded in the frontend pages). Are there any other CMSs that are similar to this?

**editEase Demo**
http://jquerystuff.com/editease/ - Admin link is at the bottom-right
user: admin
pass: pass

Comment: I have exactely the same question, did you find an alternative ?

Comment: Check out Instant.cm

Answer (score 2):

Also, [Unify](http://unify.unitinteractive.com/).

Comment: @SoloBold: Yes, but so does editEase... right?

Comment: Whoops... yes it does :)

Answer (score 2):

There is the cms called Wakanda http://www.wakanda.org

Answer (score 1):

http://www.firerift.com/ looks really nice // there's also: calip.so (node.js + mango.db) , nodepad && murray-cms (( also node )) - via https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#content-management

Comment: What's up with Calip.so?  Is it still being developed?

Answer (score 0):

[JSCMS](http://jscms.sourceforge.net/eng/)

Comment: [Don't answer with just a link.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)